# Use List 2 to define the value of List 1

Tags: python, list, range, position

I am very new to Python and I can't seem to figure out how I can have two lists communicate with each other.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
List 1 = [a, b, c]
List 2 = [1, 2, 3]

List 1 = 'b'
print(List 2)

Output: 2
```

I am looking for the code to evaluate the position of the item in List 1 and output the result of List 2 at the same exact position. How could I do that?

If both lists are incremented numbers, can I use the range?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: this is `List 1 = [a, b, c]` invalid in python. variable names can't contain space

Comment: try this, ```List_2[List_1.index('b')]``` & as mentioned above your code is not a valid python code.

Comment: you can use dictionary `d = dict(zip(List_1, List_2))` and acces value with `d['b']` it will give `2`

Comment: Thank you @Sushanth it has worked. Sorry for not a valid code, I didn't know how to write it. Thank you again. I have just started learning programming, it's a bit hard to explain something with limited amount of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Python uses zero-based indexing. That means, the first element of `List_1`, `a` has an index `0`, the second `b` has index `1`, and so on.

If you tried accessing `List_1` elements using `List_2` like this `List_1[List_2[0]]` then you won't be able to access the first element because `List_2` does not contain `0`.